# How to select datetime with a time span taken from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have thousands of absent record in the absence table that has an User_Id and Date_Time fields.
[image]

Then I also have Time_Setting table that has the Start_Time and Finish_Time fields.
[image]

How to select Date_Time in absence table with all time span taken from Time_Setting table ?
so i want to display all record from absence table which corresponds to the Time_Setting table.

example :

```
{'2021','2018-08-30 07:20:00'},
{'2021','2018-08-30 12:01:00'},
{'2021','2018-08-30 13:00:00'},
{'2021','2018-08-30 16:02:00'},
```

> I just want to show today's absence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
select Start_Time, Finish_Time, absence.*
from time_setting ts
join absence a 
  on a.date_time>=floor(convert(float,getdate()))+convert(datetime,ts.start_time)
  and a.datetime<floor(convert(float,getdate()))+convert(datetime,ts.FinishTime)
```

Comment: thanks about that. but i have an eror 'Operand type clash: time is incompatible with float'

Comment: Sorry - left out the second conversion. Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you could use:

```
SELECT UserID, Date_Time
FROM Absence AS A
INNER JOIN Time_Settings AS TS ON CAST (Date_Time AS TIME) >= CAST (Start_Time AS TIME)
                               AND CAST (Date_Time AS TIME) <= CAST (Finish_Time AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return Date_Time in absence table with all time span taken from Time_Setting table

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Absence_Table
    INNER JOIN  Time_Setting ON CONVERT(TIME,Date_Time) BETWEEN Start_Time and Finish_Time
```